# Match phrase after token

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that comes from an IRC chat message that can look like this

`!addcom !commandName This is a command response`

Or could also look like this

`!addcom -ul=mod !commandName This is a command response`

Basically I need to get the whole phrase after the second `!commandName` and I'm having some issues figuring out how to start right after that space following that `!commandName` to get the remaining phrase.

I started with this in a regex tester and was able to select the second `!commandName` but now I need to figure out how to get the rest of the string.

```
 !+\w+
```

Comment: How about `!\w+.*$` ?

Comment: Are there any more `!` that follow in the response?

Comment: No it should only be the two, and the second one should always be the last thing before the response phrase.

Comment: it's too easy to be done without regex.:  `string.substring(string.search("!commandName") + "!commandName".length, string.length).trim()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is quite easy. Use negated character class with capture groups

```
![^ ]+\s*([^!]+)$
```

- Capture group 1 will contain the data.
- `[^ ]+` Matches anything other than a space. This pattern matches the command following the `!`
- `([^!]+)` Negated character class, matches anything other than `!`. This negation ensures that it selects the second `!something`
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zG2yU1/1)

**Example**

```
"!addcom -ul=mod !commandName This is a command respons".match(/![^ ]+\s*([^!]+)$/)[1]
=> "This is a command respons"

"!addcom !commandName This is a command respons".match(/![^ ]+\s*([^!]+)$/)[1]
=> "This is a command respons"
```

Comment: <edit>Reply to deleted comment, asked how to not include the space.</edit> Add a space - `![^ ]+ ([^!]+)$`

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT That is something that I just noticed :/. Fixed in the pattern :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to replace the initial substring you don't want.

The `.*` token will eat up all characters until the last occurrence `!<word>`.

```
var s = '!addcom !commandName This is a command response',
    r = s.replace(/.*!\w+/, '').trim();

console.log(r); //=> "This is a command response"
```